# what am i doing wrong in this register.php php code?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make a registration form using php and mysql.
i m using xampp and phpmyadmin from that and my sql queries on table 'user' is working fine.
but when i try to insert using php code it shows "user registration failed".
below is my code

register.php

```
<?php
    require('includes/connect.php');
    // If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['psw'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['psw']; 
    $query = "INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, email) VALUES('$username', '$password', '$email')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if($result){
            $smsg = "User Created Successfully.";
        }else{
            $fmsg ="User Registration Failed";
        }
        }
      ?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>BondOnNet | Register</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!-- JS -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script src="js/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="js/jquery-func.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<!-- End JS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/register.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="Register_header">
    <h1 id="logo"><a href="index.html">BondOnNet</a></h1>
</div>
<div id="register_container">
    <form method="POST" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
        <?php if(isset($smsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <?php echo $smsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
        <?php if(isset($fmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $fmsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
      <div class="imgcontainer">
        <img src="images/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <label><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>

        <label><b>Email</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

        <label><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

        <label><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
        <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="terms.html" style="color: #4CAF50;">Terms & Privacy</a></p>

        <div class="clearfix">
          <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

connect.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'test');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
?>
```

I tried so many small changes in code but none of it worked!
Plz help me sort out what i m doing wrong

Comment: `echo` your `$query` variable and copy and run the printed query directly in phpmyadmin. You'll get some insight as to why the query is failing.
<br>Additionally, use `mysqli_error($connection)` to print your query's error after its execution

Comment: What do you get on a var_dump() for your query variable $result? Place it inside your if(){ } statement to make sure it is passing the logic there as well. 
Have you tried injecting the raw query into SQL phpmyadmin if available to see if the query functions properly in SQL environment?

Comment: Try using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of quoting strings. It will help prevent sql injection and escape any weird chars too.

Comment: does the other columns from the table have default values?

Comment: For the whole community. To avoid being always, without knowing what is going on with your connection to the data base, use error detection.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for detecting errors:

```
mysqli_connect_errno() - Returns the error code from last connect call
mysqli_connect_error() - Returns a string description of the last connect error
mysqli_errno() - Returns the error code for the most recent function call
mysqli_sqlstate() - Returns the SQLSTATE error from previous MySQL operation
```

For more information and exemples: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php